# Running out of RAM memory

Tags: ruby, memory

I may need to build a hash table that may grow very large in size. I am wondering if the hash table does not fit in memory what is the best way to address this problem as to avoid having the application crash when it runs out of memory.

Use case: This hash table contains a bunch of ids that are referenced in a for loop that needs to consult the id for a particular word.

Comment: What do you mean by "very large"?

Comment: I think it really needs to be very very very HUGE for these kind of problems. Are you sure it is going to be a problem?

Comment: Yeah I am talking hypothetically though, what would one have to do if that were the case.. or lets say that there are other structures that are also occupying a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really think the hash will grow so big, then maybe you should not store this data in a hash in your ram. I don't think you can easily avoid a crash when your app runs out of memory. I guess the key is create mechanisms to avoid major memory consumption.

I don't know your situation, but I really doubt the hash table you described would make a reasonable computer run out of memory. If you really think so, maybe you should use a key value storage database (Redis is fairly easy to learn http://redis.io/) or other kind of NoSQL database.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you have data that can not be easily recreated on the fly, then you need to make provisions to get it out of RAM and onto disk. Any sort of data store will do that. You could use a flat or text file, or a YAML file.

If you need fast access then you'll be looking at some sort of database, because reading a flat/text file doesn't easily allow random access. SQLLite can do it, or a no-sql database.

If you need to allow multiple processes access to the data and have good access restriction, and/or store the data on one machine and access it from another, then you'll be looking at a database of some sort. At that point I'd look into MySQL or Postgres. I prefer the later, but they'll both work.